# Windows : how to make the panel scroll bar to be at the TOP position on loading the form

Tags: c#, winforms

In windows form - have a panel in which a text control were added. 
On opening the form , I need the panel scroll bar to be at the TOP position.ie., near to the first control.
Now when the form is opened , the panel scroll bar is at the BOTTOM.ie., at the last control.

Comment: Do you mean you want a horizontal scroll bar at the top of the panel, or the position of the slider within a vertical scroll bar to be set at the top?

Answer (score 10):

You need select the first element of your panel for the vertical scrollbar appear at top:

```
firstElement.Select();
```

Comment: This solution worked for me while the panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0; solution didn't worked??

Comment: This worked for me, but it took me way longer to try out than it should have.  I think it's counterintuitive because my user control doesn't have a cursor, so selection doesn't make sense and is not something I would have thought of.

Answer (score 9):

On load, try to set the panel's VerticalScroll property to 0

panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;

**EDIT**: Assuming you have panel1.AutoScroll = true

Setting the vertical scroll value to 0 will scroll to the top, however the vertical slider won't.

Also, maybe you have some control at the bottom of the panel that gets the focus (that should force the panel to scroll down). Setting the focus to the text box at the top of the panel will keep the scroll on top. (but then again maybe you don't want to set the focus to a control at the top)

Comment: Hey thanks.

it works with setting
    panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;

Comment: had the same issue and there was a control getting focus, thanks for that part

Comment: About: "however the vertical slider won't. " --> use ScrollControlIntoView() to fix this. prefer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42983529/4608491

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but with my own user control. I tried many things to try and get the panel to scroll back to the top after populating it with many controls.

Nomatter what I did it always put the VScroll bar to the bottom.

After exhaustive testing I found it was because my controls had the **TabStop** property set to true (default on user controls) was causing the issue.

Setting TabStop to **false** fixed it.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something with that as I only had one button in the form at the bottom and rest were labels and it was default selecting to it which I guessed forced the scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

If there are many controls added in a form, then set the tabIndex property sequentially from top to bottom. the scroll bar will set at top if any of the top control's tab index is lesser than tab index of any of the bottom control's tab index. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where I was working on a shopping app, I had an item list `UserControl` that contained a vertical list of line item `UserControl`s (all `Dock=DockStyle.Top`, if that paints a picture), and I was sending a list of items to a method in the item list control and just creating and adding all the item controls to a panel.

Not only was the control appearing scrolled all the way to the bottom, but the items were all in reverse order.  The list was in the correct sorted order, but when I sent each one to the `ItemListControl.Controls.Add()` method, it put them in reverse order.  I fixed it by using `SetChildIndex()` to place them in reverse order.

```
public void Add(ItemControl itemControl)
{
    _itemPanel.Controls.Add(itemControl);
    _itemPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(itemControl, 0);
}
```

Now that I think about it, `DockStyle.Top` might actually be why they're getting added in reverse order.  It's hard to tell because if I change the DockStyle to something else, the controls are not all showing up.

Anyway, getting the controls inserted in the correct order fixed the scrolling problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that provided you have Autoscroll set to True on any control which has that property you can say at any time:

'Scroll to the top of a Control
'(substitute Control's name in following without "[" and "]" symbols)

```
  [ControlName].AutoScrollPosition = New Point(0, 0)
```

'Scroll to the bottom of a Control
'(substitute Control's name in following without "[" and "]" symbols)

```
  [ControlName].AutoScrollPosition = New Point(0, [ControlName].Height)
```