# Reset the panel scroll position in winform application c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on winfom application c#.
I have two forms called `Welome` and `Details`.
Details contains 7 grids in the Panel.

**Scenario:**
If I click on any of the item on welcome page it will take to the Details page with seven grids. If I drag the scroll bar down, and come back after moving back to welcome form, still the scroll bar stays at the same position.

**Question:**
I want to reset the scroll position to top each time the user visits the details form, so that I can always see first grid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows : how to make the panel scroll bar to be at the TOP position on loading the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141778/windows-how-to-make-the-panel-scroll-bar-to-be-at-the-top-position-on-loading)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set `AutoScroll` to `true`

```cs
panel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

And, then in Details form's `load` event, set the `VerticalScroll`

```
panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
```

Comment: So simple! Yet, I found this way easier than subclassing!

Answer (score 2):

If Angshuman Agarwal's answer doesn't work for you, the culprit is likely that after load some control in the form is receiving focus, which will scroll into view and override any changes to the scroll position.

You *could* set `TabStop` to false, but then your form wouldn't be tabbable :(

A clunky work-around, but still relatively simple fix, is manually fire focus on the first control in your form:

```cs
yourFirstControl1.Select();
```

*See also*: [How to make the panel scroll bar to be at the TOP position on loading the form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1141778/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but still relevant. The above only worked when I added a line:

```
displayPanel.AutoScroll = true;
displayPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(displayPanel.AutoScrollPosition.X, 0);
displayPanel.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
```

Then it worked great, without having to set any tab indexes.

Answer (score 0):

What is mentioned above is fine but, you should add VerticalScroll.Value in Panel1_Paint

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint    
Panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0
End Sub
```